# Java reflect API wrapper (damn checked exceptions cluttering)

Tags: java, exception, checked

I have methods that look like this:

```
public static <U extends Entity<?, ?>> Http<List<U>> getAllFromServerThreadRun(Integer maxResults, Class<U> clazz) {
        JsonObject o2 = new JsonObject(); // TODO exception chaos im projekt
                                            // überarbeiten
        o2.addProperty("maxResults", maxResults);

        String s;
        Type t;
        try {
            U o = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
            s = (String) clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getControllerName").invoke(o);
            t = (Type) clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getListType").invoke(o);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
        }
        return new Http<List<U>>(new HttpGet(), s, "getall", t).setParams(o2).queryServer();
    }
```

Maybe 10 of them exist in my project as of now.

I there a alternative Java reflection library that hides these exceptions for me? I don't know what to do with them, and it's just clutter.

Comment: "I don't know what to do with them" that's your root problem you need to sort out. What do you actually want to happen, in each situation? Sweeping error handling under the carpet is a poor idea.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest

```
catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
}
```

Comment: hm ok silly me. then I could do that everywhere and check .getClass() for exception type in the handle() method? would that be the golden route? in handle() I throw of course runtimeexception for crap exceptions right?

Comment: Normally, I would oppose catching Exception, but in this case there are so many and they don't inherit from a common Exception

Comment: You could use getClass if you need the class. How to actually handle the Exception depends on your app and what you expect the Exception to mean.

Answer (score 2):

In java 7, you can catch multiple exception types in each catch:

```
try {
    // reflection stuff
} catch (IllegalArgumentException |
         SecurityException |
         InstantiationException |
         etc e) {
    ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
}
```

I sympathise with you wanting to `catch (Exception e)` because of the numerous types of exceptions thrown by reflection methods, but doing so carries the danger of jnintentionally catching unchecked Exceptions, like `NullPointerException` which may mask bugs.

If you're still in java 6 land, you're better just sucking it up I'm afraid.

Comment: +1, preferable. A "catch (Exception e)" will catch unexpected exceptions too and that may hide nasty bugs.

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 7, all reflection-related exceptions extend [java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ReflectiveOperationException.html), so you only need to catch that.

The other exceptions (IllegalArgumentException and SecurityException) are unchecked exceptions which you should not be catching at all.  If either of those occurs, there's an error in your code.  The proper thing to do is not to catch the exception, but to fix the code that is causing the exception.

Specifically, I can see just looking at the code that IllegalArgumentException will never occur, because it only happens if you pass an object to `invoke` which is not the right type, and I can see that you are passing an instance of the very class whose methods you're invoking.  And SecurityException should only happen if you aren't allowed to access the methods at all.